# Python: sum values of the third column if two columns have the same value

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have the following dataframe `df`

```
df
    a   b   i
0   1.0 3.0 2.0
1   1.0 3.0 3.0
2   1.0 3.0 1.0
3   1.0 3.0 3.0
4   1.0 3.0 7.0
5   1.0 3.0 8.0
6   1.0 4.0 4.0
7   1.0 4.0 0.0
8   1.0 3.0 2.0
9   1.0 3.0 1.0
10  1.0 3.0 2.0
```

I want to make the sum over `i` for the same couple `a` and `b`, so

```
df2
    a   b   i
0   1.0 3.0 31.0
1   1.0 4.0 4.0
2   1.0 3.0 0.0

df2 = df2.groupby(['a', 'b']).sum(['i']).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need add column `i` to the end of `groupby`, then it is use for `sum` function:

```
df2 = df2.groupby(['a', 'b'])['i'].sum().reset_index()
print (df2)
     a    b     i
0  1.0  3.0  29.0
1  1.0  4.0   4.0
```

Or add parameter `as_index=False` for return `df`:

```
df2 = df2.groupby(['a', 'b'], as_index=False)['i'].sum()
print (df2)
     a    b     i
0  1.0  3.0  29.0
1  1.0  4.0   4.0
```

Another solution if necessary is use `Series`:

```
df2 = df2.i.groupby([df2.a,df2.b]).sum().reset_index()
print (df2)
     a    b     i
0  1.0  3.0  29.0
1  1.0  4.0   4.0
```

EDIT:

If need difference of groups by position in `df` use `groupby` by `Series` `g` with [`aggregate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
ab = df2[['a','b']]

#compare shifted values    
print (ab.ne(ab.shift()))
        a      b
0    True   True
1   False  False
2   False  False
3   False  False
4   False  False
5   False  False
6   False   True
7   False  False
8   False   True
9   False  False
10  False  False
```

```
#check at least one True
print (ab.ne(ab.shift()).any(1))
0      True
1     False
2     False
3     False
4     False
5     False
6      True
7     False
8      True
9     False
10    False
dtype: bool
```

```
#use cumulative sum of boolean Series
g = ab.ne(ab.shift()).any(1).cumsum()
print (g)
0     1
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     1
5     1
6     2
7     2
8     3
9     3
10    3
dtype: int32
```

```
print (df2.groupby(g).agg(dict(a='first', b='first', i='sum')))
     a    b     i
1  1.0  3.0  24.0
2  1.0  4.0   4.0
3  1.0  3.0   5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

you want to compare to see if the prior `a, b` combination has changed and do a `cumsum` to establish a grouping array

```
ab = df[['a', 'b']].apply(tuple, 1)

df.groupby(ab.ne(ab.shift()).cumsum()) \
  .agg(dict(a='last', b='last', i='sum')) \
  .reindex_axis(df.columns.tolist(), 1)
```

[image]

---

***break it down***

- `ab = df[['a', 'b']].apply(tuple, 1)`

  - get me a series of tuples so I can see if the combination changed
- `ab.ne(ab.shift())`

  - check if tuple is not the same as previous tuple
- `ab.ne(ab.shift()).cumsum()`

  - if it isn't, then add the `True` value to the cumumlative sum.  This will create a handy grouping for each contigous set of identical pairs of `a` and `b`
- `.agg(dict(a='last', b='last', i='sum'))`

  - just specifying what to do with each column in each group.  Get the last value for `a` and `b`, which is fine since I know its the same throughout the group.  Sum over column `i`
- `.reindex_axis(df.columns.tolist(), 1)`

  - get my column order the way it was